# Stuck at Learnpython.org Tutorial (Regarding Functions)

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I've just started learning Python a few hours ago, and there seems to be a problem that I simply can't seem to get.

They ask me to:

1. Add a function named list_benefits()- that returns the following list of strings: "More organized code", "More readable code", "Easier code reuse", "Allowing programmers to share and connect code together"
2. Add a function named build_sentence(info) which receives a single argument containing a string and returns a sentence starting with the given string and ending with the string " is a benefit of functions!"
3. Run and see all the functions work together!

I've googled this question, but all of them seem to be for previous versions of python, I was hoping for an updated way to do this.

Given Code:

```
def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    list_of_benefits = list_benefits()
    for benefit in list_of_benefits:
        print build_sentence(benefit)

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```

Expected output:

```
More organized code is a benefit of functions!
More readable code is a benefit of functions!
Easier code reuse is a benefit of functions!
Allowing programmers to share and connect code together is a benefit of functions!
```

What I have tried:

```
def list_benefits():
    benefits_list = ["More organized code", "More readable code", "Easier code reuse",           "Allowing programmers to share and connect code together"]
    return benefits_list
def build_sentence(benefit):
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!" % list_benefits()

def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    list_of_benefits = list_benefits()
    for benefit in list_of_benefits:
        print(build_sentence(benefit))

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```

Output:

```
['More organized code', 'More readable code', 'Easier code reuse', 'Allowing programmers to share and connect code together'] is a benefit of functions!
['More organized code', 'More readable code', 'Easier code reuse', 'Allowing programmers to share and connect code together'] is a benefit of functions!
['More organized code', 'More readable code', 'Easier code reuse', 'Allowing programmers to share and connect code together'] is a benefit of functions!
['More organized code', 'More readable code', 'Easier code reuse', 'Allowing programmers to share and connect code together'] is a benefit of functions!
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call the `build_sentence()` function, you only want it to build a sentence using a single benefit, which you specify in its `benefit` argument.

```
def build_sentence(benefit):
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!" % benefit
```

For each iteration of this loop:

```
for benefit in list_of_benefits:
    print(build_sentence(benefit))
```

a single benefit is passed to the `build_sentence()` function, and that's what you want to print.

Comment: Thank you so much, they were all great answers, I'm shocked how quickly people respond here! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is:

```
def build_sentence(benefit):
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!" % benefit
```

Your call in `name_the_benefits_of_functions` to `list_benefits()` is storing the resultant list in your local variable `list_of_benefits`.  Now you iterate over that (correctly), but in your `build_sentence` function you are repeatedly getting a new list of benefits.  Rather than do that, just add the single `benefit` that was passed in.

I know you are new to Python, so welcome.  I am sure you will get to the section on `generators`, but here is a modified example using one for the fun of it.

```
def list_benefits():
    benefits_list = ["More organized code", "More readable code", "Easier code reuse", "Allowing programmers to share and connect code together"]
    i = 0
    while i < len(benefits_list):
        yield benefits_list[i]
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I just got stuck on the same problem. My `name_the_benefits_of_functions()` function is a bit rubbish, because it just repeats four times, rather than failing gracefully when `list_of_benefits` runs out, but here's what worked for me:

```
# Modify this function to return a list of strings as defined above
def list_benefits(count): #just a list of benefits. It spits out whatever number 'count' happens to be
    list_of_benefits = ["More organized code", "More readable code", "Easier code reuse", "Allowing programmers to share and connect code together"]
return list_of_benefits[count]

# Modify this function to concatenate to each benefit - " is a benefit of functions!"
def build_sentence(benefit): #tacks on the sentence end, and that's it
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!" % benefit

def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    count = 0
    while count < 4: # not very graceful, but oh well
        benefit = list_benefits(count)
        print build_sentence(benefit)
        count += 1

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the list of strings to the function build_sentence when you should be passing the function each of the strings in the list in turn.

```
list_of_benefits = list_benefits()
for item in list_of_benefits:
    print build_sentence(item)
```

You also need to format your code in questions here so it is easier to decipher.

I hope I have understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. It took my a while I got acronyms, the whole gamma of errors and all type of fireworks but the right answer.

At the end... I realized that you don't really need all the spaghetti of functions (as the ones they have set. -I was trying to make those functions work as I thought it was required; but it is not. So I was amazed I got the pop up to move to the next chapter.

Lesson I learned?..To differentiate between *return* and *print* and use it.

Well enough said. Here is the code!:

```
# Modify this function to return a list of strings as defined above
s= ("More organized code", "More readable code", "Easier code reuse", "Allowing programmers to share and connect code together")
def list_benefits(s):
  for b in s:
    return b

def build_sentences(s):
  for b in s:
    print b + " is a benefit of functions!"

list_benefits(s)
build_sentences(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner, and this is my answer which works

def list_benefits():

```
benefit_list= ["More organized code","More readable code", "Easier code reuse","Allowing programmers to share and connect code together"]

return benefit_list
pass
```

def build_sentence(benefit):

```
return benefit + " is a benefit of functions!"

pass
```

def name_the_benefits_of_functions():

```
list_of_benefits = list_benefits()

for benefit in list_of_benefits:

    print build_sentence(benefit)
```

name_the_benefits_of_functions()

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER (short & sweet):

```
    # Modify this function to return a list of strings as defined above
def list_benefits():
    return "More organized code", "More readable code", "Easier code reuse", "Allowing programmers to share and connect code together"



# Modify this function to concatenate to each benefit - " is a benefit of functions!"
def build_sentence(benefit):
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!" % benefit


def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    list_of_benefits = list_benefits()
    for benefit in list_of_benefits:
        print build_sentence(benefit)

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```

Get rid of your list, just return the strings.